# PHP Web Scrape with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, scrape

I am trying to get a data field using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. I can pull the links, images etc but cannot get a certain data attribute.

Example HTML -

```
<div id="used">
    <div id="srpVehicle-1C3CCCEG2FN601809" class="vehicle" data-vin="1C3CCCEG2FN601809">
    <div id="srpVehicle-1C3CCCEG2FN601810" class="vehicle" data-vin="1f2CfCEG2FN266778">
</div>
```

I would like to get all the "data-vin" fields on a site.

Here is my go at it -

```
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find("div[data-vin]", 0) as $vin){
  echo $vin."<br>";
}
```

But it returns the whole page when I echo $vin. How can I access that data-vin field?

Comment: Looking at [the documentation](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm) I think you want to use: `$html->find("div[data-vin]", 0)`.

Comment: I would use `domdocument` and an xpath.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct. It returns the whole page though when I echo $vin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$html->find("data-vin", 0)
```

is looking for tags *named* `data-vin`, when you really want tags *with the attribute* `data-vin`.

```
foreach($html->find("[data-vin]") as $tag){
    echo $tag->getAttribute('data-vin')."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it gives me the error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on integer

Comment: @RyanD I left in something incorrect from the original code. Please see edit.